# arcpy.Delete_management not working?

Tags: arcpy, delete, attributeerror, tkinter, error-000258

I've updated the code with the suggestions in the code but still not working.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r'F:\EGM722 - Customising GIS apps\Assignment\folklore.gdb'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.Delete_management('folklore_shape.shp')
#arcpy.Delete_management(r'F:\EGM722 - Customising GIS apps\Assignment\folklore_shape.shp')
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management('Folklore', 'x_coord', 'y_coord', 'folklore_Layer', "PROJCS['IRENET95_Irish_Transverse_Mercator',GEOGCS['GCS_IRENET95',DATUM['D_IRENET95',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',600000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',750000.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-8.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.99982],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',53.5],UNIT['Meter',1.0]];-5022200 -15179500 10000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;0.001;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision", '#')
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("folklore_Layer", "F:\EGM722 - Customising GIS apps\Assignment", "Folkore_shape.shp")
```

I've tried arcpy.Delete_management('folklore_shape.shp') and arcpy.Delete_management(r'F:\EGM722 - Customising GIS apps\Assignment\folklore_shape.shp')

Getting error;

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1542, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "F:\EGM722 - Customising GIS apps\Assignment\folklore - 22-04-18 - diff_folder.py", line 132, in new_record
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("folklore_Layer", "F:\EGM722 - Customising GIS apps\Assignment", "Folkore_shape.shp")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 1891, in FeatureClassToFeatureClass
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000258: Output F:\EGM722 - Customising GIS apps\Assignment\Folkore_shape.shp already exists
Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).
```

Creating the event layer works it is the delete part that isn't working.

Comment: Your code is creating a feature class in a geodatabase where as you are trying to delete a shapefile in the folder where the geodatabase is located.

Comment: `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True`

Comment: Also don't forget your raw string: `arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("folklore_Layer", r"F:\MyProject\Assignment", "folklore_shp")`

Comment: Does it work if you set `arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\temp'`?  If not, does it work if you use a [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) that does not involve Tkinter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in this part of your code:

```
if arcpy.Exists(r'F:\MyProject\Assignment\folkore_shp.shp'):
   arcpy.Delete_management(r'F:\MyProject\Assignment\folkore_shp.shp')
```

folklore is misspelled.

Fix:

```
if arcpy.Exists(r'F:\MyProject\Assignment\folklore_shp.shp'):
   arcpy.Delete_management(r'F:\MyProject\Assignment\folklore_shp.shp')
```

Also, as commented:

`arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True`

And don't forget your raw string for folder paths (or anything with a backslash):

`arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("folklore_Layer", r"F:\MyProject\Assignment", "folklore_shp")`

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> If I don't comment out `arcpy.env.workspace.overwriteOutput = True` I
>   get:
>
> > arcpy.env.workspace.overwriteOutput = True AttributeError: 'unicode'
> >     object has no attribute 'overwriteOutput'

This is because the code should be:

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
```

not:

```
arcpy.env.workspace.overwriteOutput = True
```

Comment: Think you meant: arcpy.env.overwriteOutput rather than workspace.

Comment: Thanks @dslamb - I had edited out the wrong bit - corrected now.

Comment: Hi Folks sorry for delay in getting back, I've looked at all comment but this still isn't working.

Comment: I've updated code above

Comment: This is working now. The code was working, I think it was to do with locks on the shape file.